# Difference between Samsung Smart TV apps with scenes and without?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

Just a quick question. I'm using Samsung Smart TV SDK 5.1 and there are few JavaScript app templates. Cannot figure out why the template that uses scenes has this in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the other one (without scenes) has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>

        <!-- TODO : Common API -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>       

        <!-- TODO : Javascript code -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/Main.js"></script>

        <!-- TODO : Style sheets code -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/stylesheets/Main.css" type="text/css">

        <!-- TODO: Plugins -->

    </head>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scenes template includes Samsung's Framework loader.

Other template don't, and instead include couple platform API scripts.

You should really read developer guide http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=art00114&FileName=index.html